# Using VBA Sum Function to Transfer Data Between Sheets

Tags: vba, sum

I'm working on a looping data entry script. In some of the cells using the sum function is useful as the data could be in one of many adjacent cells, where knowing which cell it will be in is unpredictable, and all other cells in the range will predictably be zero.

I start by naming my variables

```
Dim file As Variant, I As Integer, Cval As String
```

Input my folder and begin the loop and open the workbook

```
file = Dir("C:\Users\test\")
While (file <> "")
Workbooks.Open (file)
```

Next I create another variable with an initial value in cell A3 and grab the file name from each row as I increases.

```
I = 1
Cval = Workbooks("VBA Practice Workbook").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 1) & ".xls"
Do Until Cval = file
  I = I + 1
  Cval = Workbooks("VBA Practice Workbook").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 1) & ".xls"
  Loop
```

The script runs through the first page and the second without issue

```
Workbooks(file).Sheets("Cover Page").Range("E39:J39").Copy
Workbooks("VBA Practice Workbook.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Workbooks(file).Sheets("Cover Page").Range("E41:J41").Copy
Workbooks("VBA Practice Workbook.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Workbooks(file).Sheets("Scoring (pg 1)").Range("B59:C59").Copy
Workbooks("VBA Practice Workbook.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Then I switch to using the sum function and I get an error message. Any idea what could be causing my problem?

```
Workbooks("VBA Practice Workbook.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Range (Cells(I, 6) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Workbooks(file).Sheets("Scoring (pg 2)").Range("B6:B14")))
Workbooks("VBA Practice Workbook.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range (Cells(I, 7) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Workbooks(file).Sheets("Scoring (pg 2)").Range("C6:C14")))
```

Comment: What was the error message? That usually gives the best indication of what the problem might be.

Comment: The `Workbooks("VBA Practice Workbook.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Range (Cells(I, 6) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Workbooks(file).Sheets("Scoring (pg 2)").Range("B6:B14")))` statement makes no sense - you can't pass `True` or `False` as parameters to the `Range` property

Comment: You need to fully qualify the `Cells(I,6)` reference. The workbook and worksheet are not specified and it's likely causing some confusion.

Comment: The error message was "Object doesn't support this property or method" error 438

Comment: I'm also struggling with a copy destination function. The error message I get is an object defined error                                                                                                                `Range(Cells(I, 26), Cells(I, 27)).Select Workbooks(file).Sheets("Scoring (pg 4)").Range("B4:C4").Copy Destination:=Workbooks("VBA Practice Workbook.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(I, 26), Cells(I, 27))`

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are trying set certain cells on Sheet1 to the sum of cells on sheet "Scoring (pg 2)".

But your current statements are comparing the value of `Cells(I, 6)` of the active sheet to the value calculated by the `Sum` and then, depending on whether that comparison returns `True` or `False`, using the result as the parameter to a `Range` property.

I **believe** you are trying to do:

```
Workbooks("VBA Practice Workbook.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 6).Value = _
   Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Workbooks(file).Sheets("Scoring (pg 2)").Range("B6:B14"))
Workbooks("VBA Practice Workbook.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 7).Value = _
   Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Workbooks(file).Sheets("Scoring (pg 2)").Range("C6:C14"))
```

I have left your original workbook names in that code, but you may like to decide whether it is a `.xls` or a `.xlsm` workbook that is being written to.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. The code is looping correctly now

Comment: Thanks for your help @YowE3k.  
I'm also struggling with a copy destination function. The error message I get is an object defined error. Can you spot what I overlooked in this function. I'd hate to have to use copy and paste since I know that it will slow my script down significantly.                                                                                                         `Range(Cells(I, 26), Cells(I, 27)).Select Workbooks(file).Sheets("Scoring (pg 4)").Range("B4:C4").Copy Destination:=Workbooks("VBA Practice Workbook.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(I, 26), Cells(I, 27))`

Comment: @mresner (1) `Range(Cells(I, 26), Cells(I, 27)).Select` is a waste of time. (2) `Workbooks(file).Sheets("Scoring (pg 4)").Range("B4:C4").Copy Destination:=Workbooks("VBA Practice Workbook.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(I, 26), Cells(I, 27))` should be `Workbooks(file).Sheets("Scoring (pg 4)").Range("B4:C4").Copy Destination:=Workbooks("VBA Practice Workbook.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Workbooks("VBA Practice Workbook.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 26), Workbooks("VBA Practice Workbook.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 27))` or, more simply, ....

Comment: `Workbooks("VBA Practice Workbook.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Z1:AA1).Offset(I-1,0).Value = Workbooks(file).Sheets("Scoring (pg 4)").Range("B4:C4").Value`  (I **hope** - it's a bit hard to answer questions when written in comments - it should be a new question.)